# Type ViewController does not conform to protocol GIDSignInDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using Swift in Xcode and I have 2 problems with my code. I'm using the Firebase Auth and inside my viewController there are 2 errors. Can anyone help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: For me also same error coming if you got solution for that please give me the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add These function to your code :-

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {...}
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {...}
```

For future reference , if you ever see this error just **cmd+click** the `delegate` in your case *GIDSignInDelegate* protocol that your class is not conforming to and you will see a bunch of function written in that protocol that needs to be conformed by this class - which is to inherit from that `protocol`, include those function in your class and you are golden..(Mostly)

PS:- some protocol functions are marked **optional** meaning including them is up to you and you wont face this error if you dont, but some which are not are mandatory.